# Query to fetch most recent record when joining multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables (relevant columns only)

```
Users: userId, email
EventRegistrations: userId, eventId
Events: id, time
```

Am trying to fetch the most recent event a user attended. From my research, it seems I have to do a subquery on max(time) inside one of the joins, but have had no luck.

Sample data:

Users:

```
email          userId
test@test.com  1
test2@test.com 2
```

EventRegistrations:

```
userId eventId
1      10
1      11
1      12
2      11
2      13
```

Events:

```
id      time
10      2020-12-10
11      2020-12-11
12      2020-12-12
13      2020-12-13
```

Expected result:

```
email            eventId
test@test.com    12
test2@test.com   13
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
select u.email, e.id 
from users as u
left join EventRegistrations as er on e.ruserId = u.userId
left join Events as e on e.id = er.eventId
JOIN (
    select MAX(time), er.userId
    from Events as e
    left join EventRegistrations as er on er.eventId = e.Id
    group by er.userId
) as mostRecentEvent
ON mostRecentEvent.userId = er.id;
```

Previously I had

```
select u.email, e.id
from users as u 
left join EventRegistrations as er on er.userId = u.userId
left join Events as e on e.id = er.EventId
group by u.userId
order by e.time desc
```

But the problem there is that Group By is applied before the sorting, hence why I thought I needed a subquery with max to fetch the most recent event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a correlated subquery:

```
select u.*,
       (select e.eventid
        from EventRegistrations er join
             Events e
             on er.eventid = e.id
        where er.userid = u.id
        order by e.time desc
        limit 1
       ) as eventid                 
from users u
```

Comment: Thanks did did the trick. I had to add an additional 
where u.userId in (select userId from EventRegistrations)
at the bottom to weed out NULL values.
There might've been a more elegant/efficient solution to remove NULL values, but this worked.